# Save for Web using Photoshop Actions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I would like to create an action, at the end of which I would like to save the file using Save for Web option.

The problem is the action is not being generic as it is remembering the static path of the output folder which is not being overridden during batch operations as well.

For example if I save the file inside `C:\Pictures` in the `Save for Web` Action and then during the Batch operation I specify the output folder as something else, it is still considering the former one.

Is it possible to make this a generic action?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the `Actions` window check the `Toggle dialog on/off` box (highlighted in the image below) next to the Save for Web item (`Export`):

[image: Toggle dialog on/off]

This way, when you are running the action, the `Save for Web` dialog will pop up with the settings specified in the Action item; so if you just click `Save` you can change the path and leave the other settings intact.